# why my program doesn't give the correct answer ( to find second largest in a list) - in python

Tags: python

```
def calc_largest(arr):  
    second_largest = arr[0]  
    largest_val = arr[0]  
    for i in range(len(arr)):  
        if arr[i] > largest_val:  
            largest_val = arr[i]  
  
    for i in range(len(arr)):  
        if arr[i] > second_largest and arr[i] != largest_val:  
            second_largest = arr[i]  
  
        return second_largest

print(calc_largest([20, 30, 40, 25, 10])) # this outputs correct answer

a=[]
n=int(input("Number of elements in array:"))
for i in range(0,n):
    l=int(input("Enter the element"))
    a.append(l)
print(a)# list is printed properly
print(calc_largest(a))# Always prints the first input entered by me
```

Comment: unindent `return second_largest` to match the `for` indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with your indentation. Your return happens in the for loop after the first iteration. Just move it out. Note that you could also get it via second_largest = sorted(arr)[-2]

Comment: I moved out the return statement. works fine now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

```
def calc_largest(arr):
    return sorted(arr)[-2]
```

Comment: works fine. Thanks a lot